# How to handle Behaviors in Prism with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

How to handle behaviors with Prism? I have the following code and I would like to know how to handle the "enrtyEmail.IsValid" property? How can I find out in the ViewModel the status of the EmailValidatorBehavior ?

```
<Entry x:Name="entryEmail">  
  <Entry.Behaviors>  
    <local:EmailValidatorBehavior />  
  </Entry.Behaviors>  
</Entry>
```

Answer (score 2):

A Behavior is a BindableObject, so you can simply add a BindableProperty to your EmailValidatorBehavior.

```
public class EmailValidatorBehavior : BehaviorBase<Entry>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsEmailValidProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create( nameof( IsEmailValid ), typeof( bool ), typeof( EmailValidatorBehavior ), false, BindingMode.OneWayToSource );

    public bool IsEmailValid
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue( IsEmailValidProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( IsEmailValidProperty, value ); }
    }
}
```

and then bind to that property from your ViewModel

```
<Entry Text="{Binding EmailAddress}">  
  <Entry.Behaviors>  
    <local:EmailValidatorBehavior IsEmailValid="{Binding IsEmailValid}" />  
  </Entry.Behaviors>  
</Entry>
```

EDIT: Note that without setting the BindingMode the binding will not propagate from the Behavior to the ViewModel. Given the nature of the setting the most appropriate BindingMode would be `OneWayToSource` as this makes the property effectively read only for the ViewModel.

see https://github.com/dansiegel/Validation-With-Prism-Behavior for a working example

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the IsEmailValid property doesn't change state inside my ViewModel.In the behavior, I can see that the "return GetValue" is returning true when the email is valid, but in my ViewModel the IsEmailValid remains false!

Comment: @Dimitris See the edit. You just need to set the BindingMode.

Comment: I did the change but I get the same result. Nothing changed!

Comment: There are 2 changes between the code that you posted and my code. The first is that I have curly braces in the XAMl binding i.e. (otherwise I get a compile time error)
IsEmailValid="{Binding IsEmailValid}"
the second is that I have a "(bool)" cast in the property
return (bool)GetValue(IsEmailValidProperty); (otherwise I get a compile time error)

Comment: Yes sorry about the typo... looks like you have it figured out now though :)

Comment: Anyway, regardless of the type, it doesn't seem that the ModelView gets notified about the "IsEmailValid" property.

Comment: @Dimitrissee the example provided. It's not using an actual email verification, but if you type more than 2 characters you'll see the `IsValid` Binding changes from false to true.

Comment: The problem is that I don;t see that change from False to True in my ViewModel. I can see that the validator is working but the binding with the ViewModel is not working!

Comment: @Dimitris If you're following the example I shared with you it should work. If you're having trouble please post a link to a sample replicating our problem.

Comment: You can find the example [here](https://github.com/gnout/ExampleBehaviors) In my ViewModel (MainPageViewModel) the IsValid property never gets updated. As a result when pressing the button I'm getting always the alert that the email address is NOT valid.

Comment: Make two changes to your code. Update to Prism.Forms 6.3.0-pre2 and change your Behavior to inherit from [`Prism.Behaviors.BehaviorBase<T>`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/Behaviors/BehaviorBase%7BT%7D.cs) instead of `Xamarin.Forms.Behavior<T>`